# menu should hide when not being hovered over with timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout

What I am trying to accomplish is having a menu that will show up when a "button" is clicked (the button and menu are in separate elements so the mouse is not hovering over the menu initially).

The menu should hide itself if it is not hovered over within the duration of the timeout (currently it does this, but only the first time it is clicked).

Also, if the element gets hovered over, I would like hide on mouseout and clear the timer and clicking the button again would reset the timeout (it is not resetting maybe?).

I have tried several incarnations and nothing I have tried has behaved correctly and am looking for advice. This his is what I am currently using:

```
var mytimer = window.setTimeout(function() {$('.menu-div').slideUp(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(this.mytimer);
})
}, 5000);

$().ready(function(){

    $('#menu-button').click(function () {
        $('.menu-div').slideDown();
        $(mytimer);
    });

    $('.menu-div').mouseenter(function() {
       window.clearTimeout(this.mytimer);
    });

    $('.menu-div').mouseout(function() {
        $('.menu-div').slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where else is `garagetimer` used? Your code only uses it to clear the timeout...

Comment: Assume you want to reactivate timers but not clear at all what behavior expected is. garagetimer is not defined as a `setTimout` anywhere. Currently `myTimer` only gets activated when page loads. Code that doesn't work is never a good substitute for explanation of what it is supposed to do

Comment: Sorry, garagetimer should not be in there. that was a typo.

Comment: And yes, I want the timer to reactivate when the button is clicked.

Comment: You're using var mytimer and this.mytimer as if they're the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I must have misunderstood the examples I was looking at. Will mess with it some more and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this (just a guess, because you didn't give any HTML)

```
$(function(){
    var mytimer=0;  
    $('#menu-button').click(function () {
        $('.menu-div').slideDown();
        mytimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.menu-div').slideUp();
        }, 5000);
    });

    $('.menu-div').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(mytimer);
    });

    $('.menu-div').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.menu-div').slideUp();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCUDP/).

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was after. After the previous comments I was able to figure it out. The question I have is, why set the timer to 0? Doesn't just declaring it as var mytimer; work? Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Justin, It's ok to just declare it.